# Yii GridView widget - center align pagination

Tags: gridview, yii2, pager

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n<div class=''>{pager}</div>",
    'columns' => $columns,
]);
```

By default GridView widget renders the pagination as `ul` tag and I want to change this to use `table` instead.

Comment: Explain better. show sample

Comment: Probably you'll have to overwrite the `yii/helpers/BaseHml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`align="center"` can do your job. see code.

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n<div align='center'>{pager}</div>",
    'columns' => $columns,
]);
```

Comment: align="center" is deprecated with HTML5. Use the answer from Liz, class="text-center" instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n<div class='text-center'>{pager}</div>",
    'columns' => $columns,
]);
```

Comment: @olegtaranenko: There is no link in answer.

Comment: Yii2 includes already bootstrap, the class 'text-center' is own bootstrap. No need for this reference link.

Answer (score 0):

For [bootstrap 4](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4/doc/api/2.0/yii-bootstrap4-linkpager) widgets use `justify-content-center` eg:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n<div class='d-flex justify-content-center'>{pager}</div>",
    'columns' => $columns,
]);
```

or

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <?= LinkPager::widget([
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]) ?>
</div>
```

See [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content).

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap4

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n<div class='mx-auto'>{pager}</div>",
    'columns' => $columns,
]);
```